# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "SYS" not found; SQL statement: select name from sys.sequences [90079-192]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, h2

I was creating a unit test class for a DAO object, using an embedded H2 database. However, when I tried to run it, I got the exception with something related to a "SYS" schema, which is no where to be found.

**RepositoryConfig**

```
package com.csms.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.csms")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:db.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RepositoryConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @Profile("prod")
    public DataSource dataSourceForProd() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @Profile("test")
    public DataSource dataSourceForTest() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .generateUniqueName(true)
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .ignoreFailedDrops(true)
                .addScript("schema.sql")
                .addScript("data.sql")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.SQL_SERVER);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(
            DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter
    ) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", String.valueOf(true));

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        emf.setPackagesToScan("com.csms.entities");
        emf.setJpaProperties(props);
        return emf;
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanPostProcessor persistenceTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
    }
}
```

**schema.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    CustomerID nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Address nvarchar(50),
    Phone nvarchar(20),
    Fax nvarchar(20),
    Email nvarchar(50),
    Overdue int NOT NULL,
    Amount decimal(18),
    OverdueAmt decimal(18),
    DueAmt decimal(18),
    Status nchar(2) NOT NULL,
    Description nvarchar(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (CustID)
);

CREATE TABLE "Group" (
    GroupID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    GroupName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (GroupID)
);

CREATE TABLE Inventory (
    InvtID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    InvtName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ClassName nvarchar(50),
    UnitID_T int,
    UnitID_L int NOT NULL,
    UnitRate int,
    SalesPriceT decimal(18),
    SalesPriceL decimal(18),
    QtyStock int,
    SlsTax decimal(18),
    Status nchar(2) NOT NULL,
    Description nvarchar(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (InvtID)
);

CREATE TABLE InvoiceType (
    InvoiceType nvarchar(2) NOT NULL,
    InvoiceName nvarchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (InvoiceType)
);

CREATE TABLE MoneyTransaction (
    TransID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    TransDate date NOT NULL,
    TransAmt decimal(18,1) NOT NULL,
    Description nvarchar(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (TransID)
);

CREATE TABLE OrderType (
    OrderType nchar(2) NOT NULL,
    TypeName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderType)
);

CREATE TABLE Payment (
    PaymentID int NOT NULL,
    PaymentNo nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PaymentDate date,
    PaymentAmt decimal(18),
    CustID nvarchar(20),
    SalesPersonID nvarchar(20),
    Description nvarchar(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (PaymentID)
);

CREATE TABLE PurchaseOrdDetail (
    OrderNo nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    InvtID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Qty int,
    PurchasePrice decimal(18),
    StockID nvarchar(20),
    QtyProm int,
    QtyPromAmt decimal(18),
    AmtProm decimal(18),
    TaxAmt decimal(18),
    Amount decimal(18),
    PRIMARY KEY (InvtID,OrderNo)
);

CREATE TABLE PurchaseOrder (
    OrderNo nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    OrderDate date,
    OrderType nchar(2) NOT NULL,
    OverdueDate date,
    DiscAmt decimal(18),
    PromAmt decimal(18),
    ComAmt decimal(18),
    TaxAmt decimal(18),
    TotalAmt decimal(18),
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderNo)
);

CREATE TABLE SalesOrder (
    OrderNo nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    OrderDate date NOT NULL,
    InvoiceType nvarchar(2) NOT NULL,
    CustID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    OverdueDate date NOT NULL,
    OrderDisc decimal(18) NOT NULL,
    TaxAmt decimal(18),
    TotalAmt decimal(18),
    Payment decimal(18),
    Debt decimal(18),
    Description nvarchar(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderNo)
);

CREATE TABLE SalesPerson (
    SalesPersonID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    SalesPersonName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Address nvarchar(50),
    StockQuota int,
    Status nchar(2) NOT NULL,
    Description nvarchar(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (SalesPersonID)
);

CREATE TABLE SlsOrderDetail (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNo nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    InvtID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Qty int,
    SalesPrice decimal(18),
    Discount decimal(18),
    TaxAmt decimal(18),
    Amount decimal(18),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Status (
    Status nchar(2) NOT NULL,
    StatusName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Status)
);

CREATE TABLE StkTransDetail (
    TransID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    InvtID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Qty int,
    Amount decimal(18),
    PRIMARY KEY (InvtID,TransID)
);

CREATE TABLE Stock (
    StockID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    StockName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (StockID)
);

CREATE TABLE StockInspection (
    StockInspID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    StockInspDate date NOT NULL,
    Description nvarchar(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (StockInspID)
);

CREATE TABLE StockTransfer (
    TransID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    TransDate date,
    FromStockID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    ToStockID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    TotalAmt decimal(18),
    Description nvarchar(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (TransID)
);

CREATE TABLE Unit (
    UnitID int NOT NULL,
    UnitName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (UnitID)
);

CREATE TABLE "User" (
    UserID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    UserName nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Password nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    GroupID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (UserID)
);

CREATE TABLE Vendor (
    VendorID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    VendorName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Address nvarchar(50),
    Email nvarchar(50),
    Phone nvarchar(20),
    Fax nvarchar(20),
    DueAmt decimal(18),
    Amount decimal(18),
    OverdueAmt decimal(18),
    Status nchar(2) NOT NULL,
    Description nvarchar(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (VendorID)
);


ALTER TABLE Customer
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Status)
REFERENCES Status (Status);



ALTER TABLE Inventory
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Status)
REFERENCES Status (Status);

ALTER TABLE Inventory
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (UnitID_L,UnitID_T)
REFERENCES Unit (UnitID,UnitID);



ALTER TABLE Payment
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (CustID)
REFERENCES Customer (CustID);

ALTER TABLE Payment
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (SalesPersonID)
REFERENCES SalesPerson (SalesPersonID);



ALTER TABLE PurchaseOrdDetail
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (InvtID)
REFERENCES Inventory (InvtID);

ALTER TABLE PurchaseOrdDetail
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (OrderNo)
REFERENCES PurchaseOrder (OrderNo);

ALTER TABLE PurchaseOrdDetail
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (StockID)
REFERENCES Stock (StockID);



ALTER TABLE PurchaseOrder
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (OrderType)
REFERENCES OrderType (OrderType);



ALTER TABLE SalesOrder
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (CustID)
REFERENCES Customer (CustID);

ALTER TABLE SalesOrder
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (InvoiceType)
REFERENCES InvoiceType (InvoiceType);



ALTER TABLE SalesPerson
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Status)
REFERENCES Status (Status);



ALTER TABLE SlsOrderDetail
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (OrderNo)
REFERENCES SalesOrder (OrderNo);



ALTER TABLE StkTransDetail
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (InvtID)
REFERENCES Inventory (InvtID);

ALTER TABLE StkTransDetail
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (TransID)
REFERENCES StockTransfer (TransID);



ALTER TABLE StockTransfer
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (FromStockID,ToStockID)
REFERENCES Stock (StockID,StockID);



ALTER TABLE "User"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (GroupID)
REFERENCES "Group" (GroupID);



ALTER TABLE Vendor
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Status)
REFERENCES Status (Status);
```

**data.sql**

```
INSERT INTO Status(Status, StatusName) VALUES ('AV', 'Active');
INSERT INTO Status(Status, StatusName) VALUES ('UA', 'Inactive');
INSERT INTO Status(Status, StatusName) VALUES ('DE', 'Deleted');
```

**StatusDAOUnitTest.java**

```
package com.csms.dao;

import com.csms.config.RepositoryConfig;
import com.csms.entities.Status;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;

import java.util.List;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = RepositoryConfig.class)
@Transactional
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class StatusDAOUnitTest {

    @Autowired
    private StatusDAO statusDAO;

    @Test
    public void testGetStatusList() {

        List<Status> statusList = statusDAO.getStatusList();
        assertThat(statusList.size(), is(3));
    }
}
```

**Stack trace**

```
org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:679)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:685)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1215)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1896)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2044)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1890)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1711)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1699)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:445)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:317)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:289)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:254)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:560)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:501)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1202)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:126)
    ... 56 more


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:253)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean' defined in com.csms.config.RepositoryConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:961)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:891)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to build DatabaseInformation
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:308)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "SYS" not found; SQL statement:
select name from sys.sequences [90079-192]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:679)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:685)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1215)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1896)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2044)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1890)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1711)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1699)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:445)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:317)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:289)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:254)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:560)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:501)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1202)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:126)
    ... 56 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I created two separated profiles "prod" and "test" for MSSQL and embedded H2 respectively, then I assigned the two datasources to the 2 profiles. But I forgot to create a new `JpaVendorAdapter` for test, so the "test" profile uses the wrong config for `JpaVendorAdapter`. All I needed was to create a JpaVendorAdapter for H2 database and give it "test" profile.

Comment: You still need to fix your schema.sql file, there are issues in it. I'll remove my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It looks like it's generally a H2 config problem. In my case, I'd left `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect` in my code, which was causing this error. Removing it fixed it for me.

Also see my other answer here which is related and may be of use for this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69354671/2478049